# sed discard after character X

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am looking for the sed command to discard the characters from the 11th (and thus conserve the 10 first one) in the lines starting by ">". So what I want basically is to change this file

```
>LEP004_Iphiclides_podalirius
GCCTCGGCTCACTTGGAAGGTGG

>LEP054_Danaus_plexippus
GGTCGTTGACCTCACTGTTTGCA
```

into the following one:

```
>LEP004_Ip
GCCTCGGCTCACTTGGAAGGTGG

>LEP054_Da
GGTCGTTGACCTCACTGTTTGCA
```

I tried this command: sed -n '/>/{s/^(.{10}).*/\1/g;p}' seq.fas > seq_modif.fas but it just output the sequence headers (and not the DNA sequences)

Thank you!

Comment: All three work perfectly, thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `sed` command:

```
sed '/^>/s/^\(.\{10\}\).*/\1/' file
>LEP004_Ip
GCCTCGGCTCACTTGGAAGGTGG

>LEP054_Da
GGTCGTTGACCTCACTGTTTGCA
```

Comment: ++ for a POSIX-compliant solution.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^>/s/.//11g' file
```

Comment: ++ for concision, but it truly requires _GNU_ `sed`:  ["Note: the posix standard does not specify what should happen when you mix the `g` and _number_ modifiers, and currently there is no widely agreed upon meaning across sed implementations. For GNU sed, the interaction is defined to be: ignore matches before the _number_-th, and then match and replace all matches from the _number_-th on."](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [`awk`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) version:

```
$ awk '/^>/ {$0=substr($0,1,10)} 1' seq.fas
```